# Razor Host installation error in dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I upgraded my IIS to .NET v4.0 successfully but on installing Razor Host, It shows the error like

*Error: is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dotnetnuke\Install\Temp\ajynte0h' is denied. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dotnetnuke\Install\Temp\ajynte0h' is denied. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj) at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create() at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Util.WriteStream(Stream sourceStream, String destFileName) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.InstallFile.ReadZip(ZipInputStream unzip, ZipEntry entry) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.InstallerInfo.ReadZipStream(Stream inputStream, Boolean isEmbeddedZip) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.InstallerInfo..ctor(Stream inputStream, String sitePath) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installer..ctor(Stream inputStream, String physicalSitePath, Boolean loadManifest, Boolean deleteTemp) at DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Extensions.Install.LoadPackage(String package) at DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Extensions.Install.Initialize() at DotNetNuke.Modules.A*dmin.Extensions.Install.OnLoad(EventArgs e) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

help me to solve this error?????

Answer (score 0):

How did you udpgrade to 4.0? Did you change the app pool? or did you change the framework for the app pool, and kept the identity the same? If the first: Have you checked that you app identity has sufficient rights on the application?

If the second: Try to re-install the razor module.